# "ImportError: No module named" error doesn't seem to be related to my code

Tags: python, python-module

I am trying to complete [Exercise 47](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex47.html) of *Learn Python The Hard Way, 2nd Edition*, but I am receiving this error when I run `tests/ex47_tests.py`:

```
File "tests/ex47_tests.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ex47.game import Room
ImportError: No module named ex47.game
```

I thought it was something I was doing wrong within my code because I am very new at this, so I cloned [this repo](https://github.com/darthlukan/ex47) from a GitHub user who seems to have successfully completed the exercise.

Not only are the relevant parts of our code identical, but I receive the same error when I try to run the `tests/ex47_tests.py` that I cloned from him. So now I am lost and hoping that someone has a solution for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the repository directory :

```
PYTHONPATH=. python tests/ex47_tests.py
```

Make sure there are no other ex47.py files/packages in your path.

Answer (score 5):

fabrizioM's answer should get it to work. Here is a little explanation.

When Python loads a file, it searches on the filesystem. So here, we have the import statement:

```
from ex47.game import Room
```

It looks for the file ex47.py on the modules search path (accessible as sys.path in Python code). The modules search path contains some directories based on the installation details of Python, the directories listed in the PYTHONPATH environment variable, and contains the parent directory of the script you’re executing. It doesn't find ex47.py on the path, but it sees there is a directory named ex47 with `__init__.py` inside of it. It then finds game.py in that folder.

The problem is that your current folder is not on the modules search path. Because ex47_tests.py was run, it has $cwd/tests on the path. You need $cwd on the path.

```
PYTHONPATH=. python tests/ex47_tests.py
```

does exactly that. It puts the $cwd on the modules search path so Python can find the source files.

You can also do:

```
python -m tests.ex47_tests
```

This will run it as a module instead of a file, while it will use the current directory as path it adds automatically to the the modules search path instead of the directory the file is located inside.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write this.

Comment: Edited the text to remove sys.path/PYTHONPATH mixing (will show up after review).

Answer (score 3):

The book asks you to copy the 'skeleton' directory and then use it for the game room exercise (#47). The skeleton directory has a "NAME" directory.

So if you copied the skeleton directory and named it ex47, you'll have another ex47 directory inside that.

```
lpthw > ex47 > ls
bin     docs        ex47        setup.py    tests
```

So when the book says "*Next, create a simple file ex47/game.py where you can put the code to test*", you assume that it is the top level ex47. Not correct! That's why the import won't resolve.

I hit the same problem too until I realized that the book calls the outer directory (the one we got by copying 'skeleton') as 'simplegame' evident from this line in the book -

```
~/projects/simplegame $ nosetests
```

So all the answers about PYTHONPATH are valid, I just wanted to explain why the import wouldn't work for you!

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with your directory structure. Here is my directory structure:

```
bin  docs  ex47  setup.py  tests

./bin:

./docs:

./ex47:
game.py  game.pyc  __init__.py  __init__.pyc

./tests:
ex47_tests.py  ex47_tests.pyc  __init__.py  __init__.pyc
```

Answer (score 0):

The project is named ex47 and there is a folder named ex47 within it.
(provided you have named your files according to his plan laid out before game.py file's code in this exercise)
When the author says create a simple file ex47/game.py he means the folder within is where the game.py file should be created and stored.

Answer (score -1):

I too had the same error; being new to python, I followed the book example and after copying the skeleton directory over, renamed any files containing 'NAME' - one existed in the test/ directory and once removed the unable to load error disappeared - check the answer/contents in Microivan directory post above.
So within the project directory only two python files should exist, game.py and ex47_tests.py - hope you got there, on to the next exercise.!!